# Modifying CSV files (with quotes) from shell scripts

Tags: unix, ksh

I have file Input-

Data-

```
A,B,C
"C=abv,O=12,D=gbl,DC=ad,F=fgi,G=c",abc123, "D=12gkh,F=gfkhl,H=jk67"
"C=abv,O=12,D=gbl,DC=adc",abc123, "D=ntms,F=jk4,H=ks9"
"C=abv,O=12,D=gbl,DC=ad,F=fgi,G=c",abc123,
```

Expected Output

```
B,C
abc123,"D=12gkh,F=gfkhl,H=jk67"
abc123,"D=ntms,F=jk4,H=ks9"
abc123,
```

1. I want to delete the records from first column ,but unable to do because inside and outside field separator are same .
2. Also want to delete the rows where third column value is blank (like –abc123,)

Tried with below sed solution ,     replaced start and end string and tried to delete the string upto

```
cat file_name|sed -e :1 -e 's@\(<ex>[^(<ex>)]*\),\(.*<ex>\)@\1+\2@;t1'

cat file_|sed -e :1 -e 's@\(<ex>[^(</ex>)]*\)&\(.*</ex>\)@\1+\2@;t1'
```

Comment: _want to delete the rows where third column value is blank_ but it's in the expected output?

Comment: yes...also I have modified excepted output and input file. please help on this

Comment: bash *or* ksh, please. Don't tag for both -- an answer using built-in shell capabilities rather than external tools (such as sed, awk, etc) will often be compatible with only one.

Comment: ...and btw, is there a compelling reason to do this in pure shell? You could have an embedded Python script in your larger shell script do this trivially.

Comment: Ok sure,I am looking answers in ksh

Comment: Which version of awk do you have? GNU awk has some extensions that'll let it deal with the quotes here.

Comment: I have Solaris 6.0 ..with nawk

Comment: BTW, are the spaces literal? A real CSV generation library shouldn't put a space between the `,` after `abc,` and `"D=12gkh,F=gfkhl,H=jk67"`. I'm curious as to whether that's in your actual data (and if so why/how it got there), or just an artifact of how it got typed up for SO.

Comment: Yes,you are correct ,this is sample data in real data don't have sapces.you can ignore them

Comment: Do you also have escaped `"fields with escaped "" inside"` ?

Comment: Is it possible that the first field is a number (without quotes) ?

Comment: Can you add an example of your second rule in input and output?

Answer (score 1):

In awk. Replace everything from the start to the `",` with `A,` then remove that too:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^.+",/,"A,");sub(/^A,/,"")} 1' foo
B,C
abc123, "D=12gkh,F=gfkhl,H=jk67"
abc123, "D=ntms,F=jk4,H=ks9"
abc123,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with rev and awk commands as below;

```
rev file_name | awk -F, '{print $1","$2}' | rev
```

> rev ; reverse lines of a file or files
>
> -F param: for the input field separator

or

```
awk  -F, '{print  $(NF-1)","$NF}' file_name
```

> NF is set to the total number of fields

Eg;

```
user@host $ rev test | awk -F, '{print $1","$2}' | rev
B,C
abc123, "nil"
abc123, "ntms"
abc123,


user@host $ awk  -F, '{print  $(NF-1)","$NF}' test
B,C
abc123, "nil"
abc123, "ntms"
abc123,
```

Comment: "A=ag,B=as1,C=ahj", adf-hjk-526-dk," F=jhk,G=dg10,H=jk17" so filed also having , ..hence it will not work with above solution.correct if I am wrong?.